# Django Pagination returns entire database on page 2

Tags: python, html, django, pagination, django-pagination

Trying to get pagination to work in `Django`. It looks fine on page 1 but when I go to page 2, I can see my entire database is shown.

**This is my code:**

```
class AdvancedSearch(ListView):
        template_name= 'saferdb/AdvancedQuery.html'

        def get(self, request):
            c = request.GET.getlist('opeclass')
            q = Question.objects.all()

            #Ugly q filtering methods

            paginator = Paginator(q, 25)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
            return render(request, 'saferdb/list.html', {'text' : count , 'contacts': contacts})
```

URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^query/$', views.QueryView.as_view(), name='query'),
    url(r'^advanced/$', views.AdvancedSearch.as_view(), name='advanced'),
]
```

template code:

```
<form method="get">

<!--- bunch of selection to filer output by --->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add template code and urls.py? Do you use Django 2.0?

Comment: added urls.py and template, yes I am using django 2.0

Comment: If something changes if you remove `<form method="post">`?

Comment: it is get in my code sorry pasted old version by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use def get method, you should`t use ListView, use TemplateView or View instead. ListView has paginate_by attr, for instance

```
class AdvancedSearch(ListView):
    template_name= 'saferdb/AdvancedQuery.html'
    paginate_by=25
    page_kwarg = 'page'
```

page_kwarg == 'page' by default and it checks your url and get data for page_kwarg value, so what you can do with ListView is this

```
class AdvancedSearch(ListView):
    template_name= 'saferdb/AdvancedQuery.html'
    paginate_by=25
    context_object_name = 'contacts'
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        c = self.request.GET.getlist('opeclass')
        q = Question.objects.all()
        ...
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AdvancedSearch, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({...})
        return context
```

that actually it

P.S. For my point of view, it's a little bit strange, that you paginate by Question model queryset but in the response queryset is called contacts. Probably, something important missed here in your code?

Comment: Used your solution to figure it out. Created a global variable that saved the query parameters and passed it to the pagination function. Thanks